# One-way ANOVA and tongue testing

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I have a pretty basic question about using a one-way ANOVA. I am performing an oral tribology experiment on pig tongues which basically means I am testing the friction of various mouthwash products after applying it to the tongue. There are approximately 10 of these products that I need to test.

Looking through the literature on ANOVA I can perform a within-subjects or between-subjects ANOVA. If my understanding is correct the within-subjects would mean that I need a set number of tongues but I would need to test each of the mouthwash products on each one. This is not plausible because of the limited surface area of the tongue and it is for this reason that I thought between-subjects would work better because I could have 10 groups and test each tongue once. I conducted a power analysis in R and it showed that I may need around 250-300 tongues. So now I am looking for a way to use these tongues more than once.

I can probably test each tongue at least twice if I cut them into two separate pieces. The question is if I cut each tongue into two different pieces can I count them as two different "subjects" or assuming the tongues are not radically different, can I just say I'm testing one material 10 different times? Basically, what I really need to know is if I assume the surface of these tongues are the same can I still use ANOVA to make an analysis or do I need to treat each tongue as a separate subject. It seems like I could, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Assuming the surface of the tongue is essentially uniform throughout, you'd count the two cut tongue pieces as one subject.  You are simply making two pieces to facilitate the experience and they are not "different" so there should be no need to treat them as different "subjects."

Comment: Cut them lengthways (left & right should be more similar than front & back). But it would still be prudent to allow for higher variability between tongues than between pieces of the same tongue by including their original owner as a factor in the model.

Comment: If there's any tendency of the response to vary across pigs (for example, perhaps because of genetic factors making tongues tougher or more fragile), then the two halves of a tongue are clearly paired (more alike than halves of tongues from different pigs). You should account for this effect in your modelling (and, hopefully, take advantage of its potentially substantial benefits in your design). ... indeed judicious use of such pairing might serve to reduce the number of halves required.

Comment: Might be useful to look into balanced incomplete block designs. There are 45 ways of pairing the 10 treatments; doubling that to swap each pair between left & right tongue halves gives 90; replicating 3 times gives 270 total observations. I'd suggest a smaller pilot study first, if you haven't already conducted one.